# Deserializing XML into POCO at runtime using inline XSD

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

As part of a REST response from Azure DevOps that's being deserialized into a number of classes,
one of the properties of the json response contain XML with inline schema information.

The schema isn't fixed, as it contains user generated tables of column names and values, formulated as XML.
So I don't know how to describe the object I'm deserializing into, prior to compilation.

How do I translate the inline schema into a runtime generated object structure, my custom deserializer can use?
Or is this even the right way of doing this?

The xml could look like this, where `<NewDataSet>` is my root element and always known. The rest depends on the user generated table.

```
<NewDataSet>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">    
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="">      
        <xs:complexType>        
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">          
                <xs:element name="Table1">            
                    <xs:complexType>              
                        <xs:sequence>                
                            <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />                
                            <xs:element name="petId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />                
                            <xs:element name="petName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />                
                            <xs:element name="petStatus" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />              
                        </xs:sequence>            
                    </xs:complexType>          
                </xs:element>        
            </xs:choice>      
        </xs:complexType>    
    </xs:element>  
</xs:schema>  
<Table1>    
    <status>available</status>    
    <petId>0</petId>    
    <petName>doggie</petName>    
    <petStatus>available</petStatus>  
</Table1>  
<Table1>    
    <status>pending</status>    
    <petId>1</petId>    
    <petName>cat</petName>    
    <petStatus>pending</petStatus>  
</Table1>  
<Table1>    
    <status>sold</status>    
    <petId>2</petId>    
    <petName>fish</petName>    
    <petStatus>sold</petStatus>  
</Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

My deserializer would pull the xml out of the json response from the root element down, like this, as it does with other known datastructures:

```
public override NewDataSet? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            // Read XML string and parse it to object of type Steps
            var xml = reader.GetString();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NewDataSet));

            Log.Debug($"Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.LocalDataSource XML: {xml}");

            using var stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
            return serializer.Deserialize(stringReader) as NewDataSet;

        }
```

Comment: Try to use [DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-7.0), [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Deserializing into DataSet using the inline XSD, is exactly what I need. If you write it up as an answer with the deserializer returning a DataSet, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-7.0) is able to load XML of the format shown, using inline XML Schema.

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml("test.xml");

label.Text = dataSet.Tables[0].TableName;

dataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Using data binding, they can be immediately displayed in the grid.

Change the `petId` type in the schema to `xs:int` and you will not be able to enter a non-numeric value into the grid cell.

```
<xs:element name="petId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
```

This serves as proof that `DataTable` uses data types loaded from Xml Schema.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @alexander-petrov answer, I ended up with this deserializing method to deal with the XML:

```
    public override DataSet Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // Read XML string and convert it into a DataSet
        var xml = reader.GetString();
        using var stringReader = new StringReader(xml);

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.ReadXml(stringReader, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);

        return dataSet;
    }
```

It'll read the inline XSD, build a DataSet with a table I can itterate through, without knowing the initial size and shape of the XML input.